# Circle ci build doesnt fail when node scipt throws error

Tags: node.js, circleci

One of my circleci steps uses a node image and triggers a script. The problem is when this fails it still shows as successful in circleci.

the part of the config.yml that triggers the script.

```
  create:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:9.11
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Run node script
          command: |
            cd .circleci/scripts/
            npm install
            node robot.js
```

The `robot.js` script (very simplified):

```
async function run() {
      throw new Error('fail');
}
run();
```

What can i do to make the circleci step fail when error is thrown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out.

Use `process.exit(1);`

So for my case the solution was:

```
async function run() {
     try {
         // Code
     } catch(err) {
         process.exit(1);
     }
}
run();
```

https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code